# Signal handling: printing something and then taking the default behaviour

Tags: linux, signals

My requirement is that whenever a program terminates in any way other than its normal completion [i.e. exit() system call at the end], I need to handle it (say, hook a print "Hello" statement) before it actually terminates.
**For example**, when I hit `Ctrl+C` while running a program, it should print `Hello` and continue the way a `SIGINT` must have been handled.
If I use my custom signal handler function (having a print statement logic) in my source code, it would alter the default behavior i.e. how `SIGINT` would have ideally terminated.

**1)** Can anyone help me achieve both of this? What other signals I need to handle explicitly (maybe `SIGTERM` ?) which can cause termination of a running process?
**2)** How can I generate/test them ?(say, `SIGINT` can be generated by hitting `Ctrl + C` in `linux`)

Answer (score 1):

there are several signals supported in unix/linux.
Except SIGKILL, SIGSTOP, all others can be interpreted and handled.
process of registering the handler to a particular signumber should be same.

We can use kill command to send signals to other process.
For example: it sends TERM signal to processid 1234
kill -s TERM 1234

Answer (score 0):

The `sigaction(2)` man page has some useful info.  For one thing, every signal but `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` can be caught.

In your signal handler, you have two options:

- `puts(3)` and then manually do something (`exit()` or `raise(SIGSTOP)` or something).
- `puts(3)` and then try to get the default signal behaviour by setting the handler back to `SIG_DFL`, and sending the signal to yourself with `raise(3)`.  I'm not sure whether you can just `sigaction()` to restore your signal handler right after `raise()` from inside that signal handler, and whether that would be portable even if it happens to work on Linux.

List all signals with `kill -l`

Send a signal with `kill -INT 1234`, or in the shell you started a background process from: `kill -INT %1`.  Or to avoid copy/pasting a PID every time: `pkill -INT process_name`  (`pkill` and `pgrep` are related.)